# Is making module method variables global good practice in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to separate the code function of a script into a new module. I want to define some configs to pass as parameters in that module. Then, in the module I define this config as global. Is it a good practice? Is there a better solution?

**main script:**

```
import myModule

config = {
    "foo1" : "bar1",
    "foo2" : "bar2",
    "foo3" : "bar3"
}

myModule.execute(config)
```

**module:**

```
def execute(config):
   global CONFIG
   CONFIG = config
   value1, value2 = handleRequest()
   print(value1)
   print(value2)

def handleRequest()
   value1 = doSomething(CONFIG["foo1"])
   value2 = doSomethingElse(CONFIG["foo2"])
   return value1, value2
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code in need of improvement belongs on Code Review.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This would be insta-closed on CR for being "example code"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I normally do when I need such kind of global variables is to make a class and define them there. So for example a Configuration class with values stored in them.

This has the following advantages (not an ending list):

- The class constants/variables 'belong' to something which is more applicable (Configuration in this case).
- The code to calculate can be hidden (i.e. functionality can be incorporated in the same class)
- Name clashes are prevented.
- If in the future there is a need for making multiple instances of configurations it is less of a problem.